# How to Recreate database tables in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, command-line, terminal

I have recently in my project needed to erase my databases and using `rails g migrate DropTable`. This has worked in making me deleting the schema, but now when I run `rails db:migrate` the schema does not repopulate with the `db/migrate` information. I am kind of stuck here. How should I go about filling up my schema.

Comment: Why would `rails g migrate DropTable` delete your schema? It should only created a migration which deletes your `DropTable` table.

Comment: Yes, that is what I did. I made the file and then I was able to fill in the file to drop my tables. Instead of using my table names I used "DropTable" for this post.

Comment: rails g migrate DropTable will not delete you schema. As my thought you  had drop database.

Comment: If you don't have database and schema then you can try 'rake db:create'.

Answer (score 0):

Try to the following `rake` or `rails`, make sure your file exists under the `db/migrate` then take `TIMESTAMP` number from file name then run like below

```
rake db:migrate:up VERSION=20171212082249 #=> 20171212082249 that mean TIMESTAMP number from file name under the db/migrate
or
rake db:migrate:redo VERSION=20171212082249 # that will run the down and then the up step
```

You can see this [`article`](https://rubyinrails.com/2014/01/03/rake-db-migrate-with-down-up-redo-rollback-options/) for more explanation.

**Additional**

```
rake db:rollback STEP=1
```

This will roll back lost one migration, if you need to rollback specific one from many then try this

```
rake db:migrate:down VERSION=TIMESTAMP #=> TIMESTAMP mean 20171212082249 this number from your migrated file name
```